# Is it possible to use turtle objects in a tkinter screen?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I wanted to make a sort of tennis game and I decided to use Tkinter, although I hadn't figured out how to add shapes or images to the screen. is there a way to use the turtle module to add objects using "object = "t.Turtle()" onto the tkinter screen?

Comment: `turtle` already uses `tkinter` to display window and `tkinter.Canvas()` to draw in this window. I don't know if there is method to add existing turtle to new tkinter window but there is method to access already existing turtle window and use some tkinter functions - ie. add tkinter.buttons.

Comment: @furas that works, so there is a way to add tkinter widgets to a turtle screen. do you know how?

Comment: first you can get access to `tkinter.Canvas()` using `canvas = turtle.getcanvas()` and later you can use `canvas.create_window(some_widget, position, ...)`

Comment: It's turtally possible. Sorry...I'll see myself out...

Answer (score 1):

`turtle` already uses `tkinter` to display window and `tkinter.Canvas()` to draw in window.

I don't know if there is method to add existing turtle to new tkinter window but there is method to access already existing turtle window and use some tkinter functions - ie. add `tkinter.Buttons`

---

This example adds one button above canvas, and one button below canvas.

```
import tkinter
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def move():
    turtle.left(30)
    turtle.forward(50)
    
# --- main ---

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
root = canvas.master

button1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Before Canvas", command=move)
button1.pack(before=canvas)

button2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="After Canvas", command=move)
button2.pack() # .pack(after=canvas)

turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

And this example puts button on canvas

```
import tkinter
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def move():
    turtle.left(30)
    turtle.forward(50)
    
# --- main ---

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
root = canvas.master

root.geometry('500x500')

button = tkinter.Button(root, text="On Canvas", command=move)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=button)

turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

You can also use other canvas functions to draw figures `canvas.create_rectangle()`, `canvas.create_image()`, etc.
See old effbot's documentation for [Canvas](https://web.archive.org/web/20190909161413/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.html) on `web.archive.org`

```
import tkinter
import turtle
from PIL import ImageTk

# --- functions ---

# --- main ---

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()
root = canvas.master

root.geometry('500x500')

# for some file formats it can work - ie. png, gif
#photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='images/lenna.png')

# for other file formats it needs `pillow` - ie. jpg, tiff, webp
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='images/lenna.jpg')

canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='center')

canvas.create_rectangle(-50, -50, 50, 50, fill='red')
canvas.create_text(0, 0, text='HELLO')

#for _ in range(12):
#    turtle.left(30)
#    turtle.forward(50)

turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]

Image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia

---

**EDIT:**

Version which adds turtle to existing tkinter window.

It uses 3 different canvas and I expect they may have different functionality - but you would have to read turtle documentation for details.

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle

root = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Label(root, text='Turtle in Tkinter')
l.pack()

# ---

s1 = tk.Canvas(root)
s1.pack()

# ---

s2 = turtle.ScrolledCanvas(root)
s2.pack()

# --- 
s3 = tk.Canvas(root)
s3.pack()
s3t = turtle.TurtleScreen(s3)

# ---

b = tk.Button(root, text='exit', command=root.destroy)
b.pack()

# ---

t1 = turtle.RawTurtle(s1)

for _ in range(12):
    t1.left(30)
    t1.forward(50)

t2 = turtle.RawTurtle(s2)

for _ in range(12):
    t2.right(30)
    t2.forward(50)

t3 = turtle.RawTurtle(s3t)

for _ in range(12):
    t3.left(30)
    t3.forward(50)
    
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I added more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Turtle has two models under which it operates, *standalone* and *embedded* (i.e. embedded in *tkinter*).  Rather than poke around in turtle's underpinnings to make standalone turtle play with tkinter, we can put tkinter in charge and call up turtles as needed.  Here's the first example provided by @furas redone in this manner:

```
import tkinter
from turtle import RawTurtle

# --- functions ---

def move():
    turtle.left(35)
    turtle.forward(50)

# --- main ---

root = tkinter.Tk()

tkinter.Button(root, text="Before Canvas", command=move).pack()

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root)

canvas.pack()

tkinter.Button(root, text="After Canvas", command=move).pack()

turtle = RawTurtle(canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Along with `RawTurtle`, the other embedded API objects of interest are `TurtleScreen` and `ScrolledCanvas` if you need more of standalone turtle's window features associated with the tkinter canvas upon which turtle crawls.